# In IOS Dev,how can I back over a page when using navigation

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

as the title,here is page A,B,C,managed by a navigationcontroller.Now I'm in A,and  I step to B,then step to C,if i press back,it will back to B,and press again is back to A.Is there any way to jump over page B when backing?

Comment: If you target iOS 6+, have a look at *unwind segues*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can jump over any UIController using the below code here  AViewController denotes your A page.  Call the below code from C to navigate to A or wherever you need.

```
  for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
                if ([controller isKindOfClass:[AViewController class]]) {
                  [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller
                                                          animated:YES];
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: It does work,thk u *。*.by the way,is there any way to del B form controller list?